# How I could make that my PC can recognize MKS SGen L V1.0

Tags: pronterface, mks, pid

I have a Custom Printer BLV, but since I bought the board, MKS SGen L V1.0, never had been possible for any PC can recognize the board. Now, I'm having an issue with the temperature calibration, and it's impossible to set a setting for the PID. Is there any way to activate something as my PC can recognize the machine?

When I use pronterface, even the software blocks itself after few minutes, due to never advancing the message connecting.

Marlin 2.0.X

[image: MKS SGen L V1.0]